# Should I use pygame.event.get() or pygame.event.poll()?

Tags: python, event-handling, pygame

I'm making an application in pygame and I need to process events. I never really understood whether  I should use `pygame.event.get()` or `pygame.event.poll()`, or if it really matters.

Question: Should I use `pygame.event.get()` or `pygame.event.poll()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) retrieves all events currently in the queue, and is usually used in a loop:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    # use event
```

[`poll()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.poll) retrieves only a single event:

```
event = pygame.event.poll()
# use event
```

In the latter, you will need to explicitly check whether the type of event is a `pygame.NOEVENT`; in the former, the loop simply won't run if there are no events.

Generally, it is more common to use the `get()` version.

Comment: What if 2 events happened between 2 lapses of the mainloop. Which event would be retrieved by poll. What with other one